# Difference between `grep '\<hi\>' coco.txt` and `grep 'hi' coco.txt`

Tags: command-line

What is the difference between: `grep '\<hi\>' coco.txt`, and `grep 'hi' coco.txt`? I applied these commands in terminal, but I do not see any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `grep`, `\<` stands for *beginning of word* and `\>` stands for *end of word*.

From `man grep`:

```
The Backslash Character and Special Expressions
   The symbols \< and \>  respectively  match  the  empty  string  at  the
   beginning and end of a word.  The symbol \b matches the empty string at
   the edge of a word, and \B matches the empty string provided  it's  not
   at the edge of a word.  The symbol \w is a synonym for [_[:alnum:]] and
   \W is a synonym for [^_[:alnum:]].
```

So, `grep '\<hi\>'` will match any line containing the word `hi` and `grep 'hi'` will match any line containing the sequence of characters `hi`:

```
$ grep '\<hi\>' <<< "hi"
hi
$ grep '\<hi\>' <<< "chimes"
$ # no output since no match
$ grep '\<hi\>' <<< "hi-fi"
hi-fi
$ grep '\<hi\>' <<< "high voltage"
$ # no output since no match
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf you are answer seems better , thank you man ,

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Radeanu , thank you, for youre help .^_^